# Android HttpPost Returns 500 through Yii Framework

Tags: android, .htaccess, yii, http-post

I've a server-side application, which is runs on `Yii Framework`. I want to reach database (MySQL) with Yii on `Android`.

So I post from client like this:

```java
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("myurl/reach");

try {
    List<NameValuePair> nmp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();

    // Parameters are here 
    // nmp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "value"));

    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nmp));
    String rs = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is **Yii's** `urlManager` rule:

```
'/reach' => 'site/reach',
```

And finally `actionReach()` method on `siteController`:

```php
if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
{
    // Reach MySQL 
} else
{
    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);   
}
```

When I tried to run application, gettin `org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error`

Here is all stack:

```java
02-22 01:11:18.803: W/System.err(3924): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error
02-22 01:11:18.823: W/System.err(3924):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
02-22 01:11:18.823: W/System.err(3924):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
02-22 01:11:18.823: W/System.err(3924):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
02-22 01:11:18.823: W/System.err(3924):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
02-22 01:11:18.828: W/System.err(3924):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
02-22 01:11:18.828: W/System.err(3924):     at com.app.myapp.PostActivity$postInfoTask.doInBackground(PostActivity.java:175)
02-22 01:11:18.828: W/System.err(3924):     at com.app.myapp.PostActivity$postInfoTask.doInBackground(PostActivity.java:1)
02-22 01:11:18.828: W/System.err(3924):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
02-22 01:11:18.833: W/System.err(3924):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-22 01:11:18.833: W/System.err(3924):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-22 01:11:18.833: W/System.err(3924):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
02-22 01:11:18.833: W/System.err(3924):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
02-22 01:11:18.838: W/System.err(3924):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Last but not least, when I change **my url** `reach/` to `reach` there's no error but Yii returns home page html output even if I posted already.

What am I missing? Is it about `.htaccess` or what?

Comment: you first need to try your yii url in your browser to see the expected output.

Comment: and check php errors on server. When i get error 500 its mostly some php error

Comment: Also check your Yii routes. Are there any special rules for "reach"? Try tailing apache logs and php error log as well

Comment: Arfeen; I tried. If not post anything, application redirects to home url correctly. Eirik Hoem; checked it already. Rules are okay. briiC.lv; I'll check this lastly, gonna post result. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer after a long research. Unfortunately, `.htaccess` is blocking `$_POST` somehow. So I decided to move my action into an **existed controller**, which works already **well**.

So, in first changed my routing rules as:

```
'reach/' => 'existed/reach',
```

And in existedController, I wrote new action which is named `reachAction`:

```
if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
{
    // MySQL Insert
}
```

This if statement is fine. Lastly, I got an instance from my model and used `$model->save();`

That's all.